# Express-validator: make field optional if other field value is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I'm trying to make the `Display Name` of a user optional if the `Anonymous` checkbox is clicked.

For that, I'm using `express-validator`.

Check the following code out:

```
router
  .route("/create-checkout-session")
  .post(
    [     
      check("displayName") //if isAnonymous : true than this is optional
        .matches(vars.intlRegex)
        .trim()
        .escape()
        .withMessage("Please provide a display name")
        .optional({ checkFalsy: true }),
      check("isAnonymous").isBoolean()],//isAnonymous
    checkForErrors,
    createCheckoutSession
```

How can I validate in one field, the value of another field, and based on that make it optional.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [if condition](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#ifcondition) to handle that case. The condition is when `isAnonymous` is NOT `true` then execute another check for `displayName`

```
router
  .route("/create-checkout-session")
  .post(
    [
      check("displayName")
        .if((value, { req }) => { // if isAnonymous : false then let's check
          return !req.body.isAnonymous;
        })
        .matches(vars.intlRegex)
        .trim()
        .escape()
        .withMessage("Please provide a display name")
      check("isAnonymous").isBoolean()
    ],
    checkForErrors,
    createCheckoutSession
```